# Video Format Analyzer

Tags: media, converters, codec, transcoding

I have a video file I don't know what format it is.

Is there a software can analyze what kind of video container / compression format it uses?

I tried Gspot, but it doesn't work (Show "Unknown format")

I am sure the file is using some kind of public standard codec because I can use a media converter convert it to avi or mpg4 file.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the picture of Gspot, but it doesn't show anything:
[alt text http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/2675/gspota.png](http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/2675/gspota.png)

When I press [1](http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/2675/gspota.png), it says DShow reports error.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the gspot window? some information there might be useful.

Comment: belongs on superuser.com

Comment: libavcodec is a programming-related answer. But I guess that this question actually belongs on superuser.

Comment: try pressing [1], what do you see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ffpmeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) (Windows builds [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mplayer-win32/files/FFmpeg/)) with the -i switch:

*ffmpeg -i myfile.avi*

FFmpeg version SVN-r19159-Sherpya, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  libavutil     50. 3. 0 / 50. 3. 0
  libavcodec    52.30. 2 / 52.30. 2
  libavformat   52.34. 0 / 52.34. 0
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libavfilter    0. 5. 0 /  0. 5. 0
  libswscale     0. 7. 1 /  0. 7. 1
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
  built on Jun 12 2009 04:25:02, gcc: 4.5.0 20090517 (experimental)
Input #0, avi, from 'myfile.avi':
  Duration: 00:00:00.41, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 363 kb/s
    **Stream #0.0: Video: rawvideo, pal8, 60x49, 12 tbr, 12 tbn, 12 tbc**
At least one output file must be specified

Comment: Yes, seems like it is a h264 file. Thanks.

Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 50.00 (50/1)
-> 25.00 (50/2)
Input #0, h264, from 'record2.avi':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: h264, yuv420p, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 50 tbc
At least one output file must be specified

Comment: It only shows the codec. Is there a way I can see the container it uses? Thanks

Comment: KenC: If you want to quickly wrap the raw h264 in a container using ffmpeg, use "ffmpeg -i myfile.avi -vcodec copy myfile_wrapped.avi" and you should get an AVI file with a single H.264 stream. This wrapping is also very fast as it is a simple stream mux.

Answer (score 1):

If you're reasonably close to a modern Linux system, try the [file](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) command. It's pretty well-educated:

```
~> file foo.mov
foo.mov: ISO Media, Apple QuickTime movie
~> mv foo.mov whatever
~> file whatever
whatever: ISO Media, Apple QuickTime movie
```

As you can see, it checks the contents of the file, it doesn't just test the filename. Not implying that the tool you tried was reliant on the filename, just trying to illustrate that it can be a powerful tool.

Comment: gspot doesn't check the filename neither

Comment: @Shay: I wasn't trying to imply a limitation in gspot, I was trying to describe file to people who might not be familiar with it. Updated my wording to hopefully reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Try mplayer in console mode. It prints file info if it detects it.
This question should be posted in superuser i guess...

Answer (score 0):

Try mediainfo. It is a great tool and gives you much more detailed information than ffmpeg or gspot.